# How can I get the GPS info from a PNG?

Tags: gps, png

I am trying to get the GPS data from several hundred PNG photographs for display in Q GIS (so need to access the EXIF data).

The online and downloadable viewers I have tried haven't yielded much information:

[image]

Do the photographs not contain any GPS info ( I am told that they do) or is there a different way of extracting the information?

Comment: The PNG standard does not contain Exif data. Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542359/does-png-contain-exif-data-like-jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agree with Devdatta, PNG Itself won't have the data.  However its possible the data could be contained in an associated file.  For example GDAL can export PNGs with the referencing stored within filename.aux.XML

Answer (score 2):

## 2017 update

EXIF data has been added to the PNG 1.2 standard, so in theory, newer PNG decoders could support location data.

See answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576717/1576548

http://ftp-osl.osuosl.org/pub/libpng/documents/pngext-1.5.0.html#C.eXIf